# UTF8 charset at JSP using russian symbols in localization. Spring MVC

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, utf-8, localization

I have made localization at my web app using English and Russian language.
But when i'm switching to Russian language it shows me "??????" instead of correct words. What the problem? But when i'm putting to my JSP Russian words, without `<spring:message code="label.login" />` it shows good. Help me pls!
This is my **messages_en.properties** file

```
label.login=Login
label.password=Password
```

This is my **messages_ru.properties** file

```
label.login=Логин
label.password=Пароль
```

**This is my login.jsp**

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%
 request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
 response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Войти в систему | Violence and Hate</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap/bootstrap.css"/>"
 rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="<c:url value="/resources/CSS/styles.css"/>" rel="stylesheet"
 type="text/css">
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/Angular/angular.min.js"/>"></script>

</head>

<body>

 <img class="img-responsive center-block"
  src="<c:url value="/resources/logo/logo.png"/>" />

<br>
 <div class="centerBlock text-center loginForm">
  <form:form method="post" action="j_spring_security_check"
   modelAttribute="users" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="validateCtrl"
   name="myForm" novalidation="true">

   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="alert alert-error">${message}</div>
    <label class="control-label" for="username"><spring:message
                                code="label.login" /></label>
    <form:input class="form-control input-sm" path="username" id="username" type="text"
     name="username" ng-model="username" required="true" />
    <div style="color: black"
     ng-show="myForm.username.$dirty && myForm.username.$invalid">
     <span ng-show="myForm.username.$error.required"><label><spring:message
                                code="label.enterlogin" /></label></span>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="password"><spring:message code="label.password" /></label>
    <form:input class="form-control input-sm" path="password" type="password" name="password"
     ng-model="password" id="password" required="true" />

    <div style="color: black"
     ng-show="myForm.password.$dirty && myForm.password.$invalid">
     <span ng-show="myForm.password.$error.required"><label><spring:message
                                code="label.enterpassword"/></label></span>
    </div>

   </div>

<div class="textCenter">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block"
    ng-disabled="myForm.username.$dirty && myForm.username.$invalid ||
  myForm.password.$dirty && myForm.password.$invalid"><spring:message
                                code="label.loginbutton" /></button></div>

  </form:form>
</div>
 <br>
<div class="text-center">
 <a href="registration"><button class="btn btn-primary"><spring:message
                                code="label.regbutton" /></button></a>
 <a href="restorepass"><button class="btn btn-primary"><spring:message
                                code="label.restorepassbutton" /></button></a>
</div>

 <script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('validateCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.username = '';
   $scope.password = '';
  });
 </script>
</body>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/Jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"/>"
 type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"/>"
 type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

This is my **mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
     "
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx">


    <context:component-scan base-package="
    com.vandh.app " />


    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/avatars/**" location="file:/resources/avatars"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />

    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    </bean>

        <bean id="multipartResolver"
   class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="5000000"/>
</bean>
<bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
         <property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="ru" />
        <property name="cookieName" value="myAppLocaleCookie"></property>
        <property name="cookieMaxAge" value="3600"></property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="locale" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>     
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">



        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And this my **web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
      <filter>
     <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>
  org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
     </filter-class>
     <init-param>
  <param-name>encoding</param-name>
  <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
     <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
     </init-param>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
    <display-name>Sample Spring Maven Project</display-name><!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet> 
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <jsp-config>
  <jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
  </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param><!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
    <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


</web-app>
```

Comment: Does the title `Войти в систему` show correctly? If so, the problem is probably that spring uses an incorrect encoding when reading from your `messages_ru.properties` file.

Comment: (we blast UTF-8 everywhere... and it is still  not enough:) Make sure that all your files are actually saved in UTF-8. Then make sure it is read as UTF-8 by spring.

Comment: @bayou.io, yeah `Войти в систему` shows correctly.

Comment: @bayou.io now i has another problem. it automaticly change russian symbols in .properties file to "?????" when i'm closing it.

Comment: @bayou.io, i solved my problem with resaving this file in UTF8 from file manager